# Free service to send generated otp to mobile via sms

Tags: php, sms

I would like to create a website login page which makes it secure for small scale website owners to use and protect from hacking of their admin password, to accomplish this instead of normal login by "User name" and "Password", I would like to do the following:

1. I will use a user name for the particular user.
2. Instead of password I need to create a Generate Button which would generate an OTP (One Time Password) every time the user tries to login to his website. Once the OTP has been generated I need a free service that could sent that generated OTP to a mobile phone via SMS.
3. If there is a network problem in mobile I need to send those OTP to a e-mail id saved during the registration period

Is there any free service that could provide my need to send an OTP via SMS?

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending software, not services – so this seems off-topic. For details, you might refer to our Meta post on [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/675/185)

Answer (score 1):

I recently did some fairly significant research into this (well not **exactly** this - just the sending of any data via sms); and the unfortunate result of that research was there are no free options available. However there is a manual method that can be done. It is unfortunately more work and less hmm guaranteed I suppose would be the word.

The method I am using to send text (which you could just as easily adapt to send a OTP) is to use the network's own email->sms gateway. Pretty much all networks have those though they may not be well advertised.

So to make that work basically in user signup/setting have a mobile phone number and then have the user select what network they are using from a predefined list. I have a small list on my own site of just Rogers and Telus as in my area (BC, Canada) and use case that covers everyone. Then just send to the gateway and you're good. Most of the gateways work by sending an email to 10digitnumber@gateway - for example 2502502500@mgs.telus.com.

The lists that I found in my research for email->sms gateways that could help you build your list were:

- http://martinfitzpatrick.name/list-of-email-to-sms-gateways/
- http://binaryoptionschannel.com/list-of-sms-gateways/
- http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/email-to-sms/
- http://martinfitzpatrick.name/article/using-email-to-sms-gateways-to-send-free-sms/
- http://www.emailtextmessages.com/

I know this is *not* perfect but it is the best I could find for myself.